# ResultMapping in fields transient

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

i can mapping a field transient.
The result mapping the dog is null, how can realize the mapping.

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "DogMapping",
entities = {
    @EntityResult(entityClass = Dog.class, fields = {
        @FieldResult(name = "Id", column = "ID"),
        @FieldResult(name = "name", column = "NAME"),

    })
}))
public class Dog implements Serializable {
  @Id 
   private Long id;
   @Transient 
    private String name;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't make it `@Transient` if you want to read it.